# How do I get the previous record in database when I update?

Tags: php, ajax, pdo

I have this history wherein I should put what I changed and the changed data. 
For example: I updated apple to mango. In my history it should be Updated apple to mango. I've tried fetchColumn but it says Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchColumn(). Here is my code:

```
    if($_POST["operationproducts"] == "Edit")
 {
  $image = '';
  if($_FILES["image"]["name"] != '')
  {
   $image = upload_image();
  }
  else
  {
   $image = $_POST["hidden_image"];
  }
    //get previous name 
    $q= $connection->query("SELECT name FROM products WHERE prodID = :prodID");
     $previousname = $q->fetchColumn();
  $statement = $connection->prepare(
   "UPDATE products 
   SET categoryID = :categoryID, brandID = :brandID, name = :name, size = :size, image = :image, price = :price, stocks = :stocks, availability = :availability, description = :description
   WHERE prodID = :prodID
   "
  );
  $result = $statement->execute(
   array(
    ':categoryID' => $_POST["categoryID"],
    ':brandID' => $_POST["brandID"],
    ':name' => $_POST["name"],
    ':size' => $_POST["size"],
    ':image'  => $image,
    ':price' => $_POST["price"],
    ':stocks' => $_POST["stocks"],
    ':availability' => $_POST["availability"],
    ':description' => $_POST["description"],
    ':prodID'   => $_POST["prodID"]
   )
  );
  if(!empty($result))
  {
    //insert to product history
    $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $previous = $previousname;
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $action = 'Updated ' . $previous . 'to ' . $_POST["name"];
    $remarks = $_POST["remarks"];
    $statement = $connection->prepare("
               INSERT INTO producthistory (userid, prodID, action, time, remarks) 
               VALUES (:userid, :prodID, :action, :time, :remarks)
              ");

    $result = $statement->execute(
               array(
                ':userid' => $userid,
                ':prodID' => $_POST["prodID"],
                ':action' => $action,
                ':time' => $date,
                ':remarks'  => $remarks,
               )
    );
    echo 'Data Updated';
  }
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed one argument :prodID.

Better use prepare statement and bind param to the missing one

```
$q->bindParam(':prodID', $prodID) or using array as your way
```

If you use query as bellow:

```
$q= $connection->query("SELECT name FROM products WHERE prodID = :prodID");
$previousname = $q->fetchColumn();
```

Should replace $previousname = $q->fetchColumn(); with $previousname = $q[0]['name'];

Or better dump your query result to see the structure!